# Typescript deserialization of concrete types in abstract list (JSON.NET serialized)

Tags: typescript, json.net

I have an object returned from an API that contains a list populated by many different concrete types (obviously with a common base). I'd like to map those items to a specific Typescript interface model-type without a bunch of manual effort.

Is there a library or technique to utilize the "$type" property JSON.NET writes to a JSON object and map that (either automatically or via a mapping configuration) to a Typescript interface/model instance? Is there another way that's not a manual mapping?

note: in my scenario, the .NET class namespace is being stripped on serialization from the API for client calls (e.g. `{ $type: 'Foo' }` instead of `{ $type: 'MyApp.Models.Foo' }`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have class instances rather than just plain objects, you have to walk the object tree via reflection and deserialize it recursively.

Here is a simple sketch:

```
class Foo
{
    name: string;

    log()
    {
        console.log("Name: " + this.name);
    }
}

class Bar
{
    age: number;

    log()
    {
        console.log("Age: " + this.age);
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    items: (Foo | Bar)[];
}

/** Type mappings. */
const types = {
    "MyObject": MyObject,
    "Foo": Foo,
    "Bar": Bar
};

const deserialize = <R = any>(instance: { $type: string }): R =>
{
    // Construct class instance.
    const ctor = types[instance.$type];
    const obj = new ctor();

    // Assign/deserialize all properties of the object.
    for (const key in instance)
    {
        const val = instance[key];
        if (val == null)
        {
            obj[key] = val;
        }
        else
        {
            if (typeof val.$type == 'string')
                obj[key] = deserialize(val);
            else if (Array.isArray(val))
                obj[key] = val.map(item => item == null ? item : deserialize(item));
            else
                obj[key] = val; // Probably some standard type 
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

```
const json = {
    $type: 'MyObject',
    items: [
        { $type: "Foo", name: "Steve" },
        { $type: "Bar", age: 42 },
    ]
};
const test = deserialize<MyObject>(json);

test.items.forEach(item => item.log());
```

This correctly prints:

```plain
Name: Steve
Age: 42
```